# Activity closed before pressing back button twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to close application after pressing back button twice. I have diffrent fragments to load on the activity. I want to close the application only when i am on the main(Home) fragment and user pressed back button twice. But it is not working properly. Here is my code to close the activity :-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        //super.onBackPressed();

        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);

    } else {
        backFlag = 1;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

It is giving me message of "Press back button twice" but fragment is no transfer to main fragment. Please help me to solve this

> Edited question

```
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();

    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

Comment: Please check you have added transaction in back stack (debug value of getBackStackEntryCount() is greater than 0 if you are on other fragment)

Comment: it is not greater than 0

Comment: Means you are not adding fragment transaction in back stack. So if you are on a fragment other than home then on back press app will exit directly, but I think you expect to go first on home and then show toast for app exit

Comment: yes, i need to do it but not succeed

Comment: So you got the problem. getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                           // Add this transaction to the back stack
                           .addToBackStack()
                           .commit(); please read this to add fragment transaction to back stack https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: If this solves your problem I can add this as answer

Comment: @ramit I am able to go back to the home fragment but after that not able to display the toast about back button press. I have edited the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121329/discussion-between-ramit-and-maheshb-psk).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by trying this alternative method by keeping two second interval to press back again:

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000; // # milliseconds, desired time passed between two back presses.
private long mBackPressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
    { 
        super.onBackPressed(); 
        return;
    }
    else { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```